# Calculating points from pixels in Java printer graphics

Tags: java, printing, graphics, measurement

I've drawn a BufferedImage on the Graphics2D object being used by a PrinterJob.

Now I'd like to know the boundaries of that image in points so I can avoid writing text over it. How can I calculate or discover that?

```
    @Override
    public int print(Graphics graphics, PageFormat pageFormat, int pageIndex) throws PrinterException {
    ...
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) graphics;
        g2d.drawImage(crossword.getImage(), null, imageableX, imageableY);
   }
```

Comment: That would be (i.getWidth() + imageableX, i.getHeight() + imageableY)

Comment: Thanks for your help.. Alas, I meant to ask how to get the boundaries in points, not pixels. The question has been edited.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work. You can of course get rid of the explanatory sysouts:

```
public static double pixelsToPoints(int pixels) {
    Toolkit tk = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
    int res = tk.getScreenResolution();
    System.out.printf("Screen resolution in DPI is %d%n", res);
    // Pixels to inches
    double inches = pixels / (1.0 * res);
    // One point is one seventy-second of an inch
    System.out.printf("Number of points taken up by %d pixels is %.2f%n", pixels, inches * 72.0);
    return inches * 72.0;
}
```

Comment: I can see how this works for the screen. But how does it work for a printer?

Comment: Sorry - I was forgetting the graphics context was a printer. With a printer, afaik the situation is that *you* specify the resolution, choosing from a range [supported by the printer](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/print/attribute/standard/PrinterResolution.html)

Comment: Thanks. Of course, best of all for my situation would be if I could determine what the resolution happens to be (in the print method would be good) rather than imposing one.

Comment: `PrinterResolution res = (PrinterResolution) def.getDefaultAttributeValue(PrinterResolution.class);` from [this](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/print/PrintService.html#getDefaultAttributeValue(java.lang.Class)) could do it

Comment: Thanks. But what's "def" and how do I get ahold of it?

Comment: 'def' would be the default `PrintService`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is the "official" solution, but it seems to work acceptably for both Microsoft Print to PDF and for my HP 6475 printer. In this method, Axis is an enumeration, X or Y, telling which dimension the calculation is for.

```
// Convert pixels to points.
private int pixelsToPoints(Axis axis, int pixels, Graphics2D g2d, PageFormat pageFormat) {
    AffineTransform xform = g2d.getTransform();

    double scale;
    if (pageFormat.getOrientation() == PageFormat.PORTRAIT) {
        if (axis == Axis.X) {
            scale = xform.getScaleX();
        } else {
            scale = xform.getScaleY();
        }
    } else {
        if (axis == Axis.X) {
            scale = xform.getShearX();
        } else {
            scale = xform.getShearY();
        }
    }

    Double points = scale / 7.2 * pixels;
    return points.intValue();
}
```